# Matlab functions - how to capture vector outputs into a single variable?

Tags: matlab, function, vector

I have a problem extracting the outputs of various functions and defining them as they are calculated. I would like to have a main document performing tasks like:

fcost(variables)

--> vector output 
f = vector output.

The exact code is as follows:

```
function fcost(hours,heatcost,slack1,slack2,realdata)


ncalc = 4 * hours;

P = zeros(ncalc*3*4,1);

if realdata == 2;

    SIN = sin((1:ncalc*4)/8)*0.5+0.7

    P(1:3:end) = SIN(1:ncalc*4);
    P(2:3:end) = slack1;
    P(3:3:end) = slack2;

else

    P(1:3:end) = heatcost;
    P(2:3:end) = slack1;
    P(3:3:end) = slack2;

end
P
format short
end
```

The problem is that the function only spits out the vector - and doesnt define anything for the main file to put to use.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that is written only **displays** the vector and doesn't return it.  This is apparent by the function header of your code:

```
function fcost(hours,heatcost,slack1,slack2,realdata)
```

This declares a function `fcost` with various parameters, but it doesn't **return** anything.  If you want to return `P` after calling `fcost`, you need to modify your function header to:

```
function P = fcost(hours,heatcost,slack1,slack2,realdata)
```

Now save this function to a file called `fcost.m`, then when it's time to use it, do:

```
P = fcost(hours, heatcost, slack1, slack2, realdata);
```

The output of `fcost` will be stored in `P`.  Because you are now returning `P`, you probably want to remove the last two verbose statements of your code.  Specifically, delete these two lines:

```
P
format short
```

Comment: Thank you for that explanation! I've been looking around for a breakdown like that, and im sure they are out there, but havent stumpled upon one yet.

Comment: @RasmusElbaek - No problem :) If I have helped and you no longer need help, consider accepting my answer.  Click on the checkmark icon that's at the top of my post, to the left below the up and down voting arrows.  Good luck!